# How can I use bootstrap in css file?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootsrap in my asp.net 4 project.

I installed bootstrap in visual studio using nuget:

[image]

I have global css file:

```
    /*Global styles*/
body, form
{
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
input[Type=text], input[Type=password], input[Type=button], input[Type=submit], input[Type=reset], input[Type=file], select, textarea
{
    margin: .2em .05em;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #333333;
}
input[Type=text], input[Type=password], input[Type=file], select, textarea
{
    max-width: 225px;
    width: 98%;
}
input[Type=text]:disabled, input[Type=password]:disabled, input[Type=file]:disabled, select:disabled, textarea:disabled
{
    background-color: #E6F6FA;
}
input[Type=button], input[Type=submit], input[Type=reset]
{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[Type=button]:hover, input[Type=submit]:hover, input[Type=reset]:hover
{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

I need to define style of the buttons and other elements using bootstrap, I want to it in global css file.

So my question how can I use bootstrap in css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the CSS file like stara_wiedzma said.
However you can't import bootstrap's .btn class for `input[Type=button], input[Type=submit], input[Type=reset]` globally with CSS

I think you are looking for something like LESS of SASS.
With LESS and SASS you can do things like:

```
input[type=button]{
    .btn;
    .btn-success;

    // your own styles...
}
```

Google: "bootstrap less workflow" for some setup and examples.

Comment: Does  LESS or SASS gives me option to import bootstrap style to css page?

Comment: Yes! You can inherrit bootstrap's classes on your own elements. The example I gave will make all buttons look like bootstrap's success button.

Comment: Can please you give some example?Or write reference to example in google??

Comment: I think this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-less will explain a lot

Answer (score 1):

@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");

Comment: where do I write it in ccs file?and how I add it to button style defenition?